# Why can't I assign a method with user defined parameters to a button in c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, user-defined-functions

I want to assign the following method to a button so that when the button is clicked the method will run:

```
private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e , string user , string pass)
    {
        frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(user, pass);
        _settings.Show();   
    }
```

I use Visual Studio 2012 and I am assigning the method to the button's click event from the events in the property panel.

What is the problem here? Before I added the tho parameter "string user" and "string pass" the function settingButton_Click was visible in the list of methods to assign to the button's click event, but as soon as I add these two parameters I can't see the method anymore in the list.

**EDIT:** I am passing user and pass arguments to this settingButton_Click through the code bellow:

```
public MainForm(string username, string password)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        settingButton_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty, username, password);
    }
```

Comment: How could that possibly work? How would those parameters get values?

Comment: You'd need to override the click event trigger, define a custom `EventArgs` and call your new delegate event handler. You're not going to be able to do any of that through the property panel. Here's [**an example**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f205d3f-9f58-4847-bbb1-4263e23d73ca/how-to-override-usercontrolonclick-event-handler-to-use-mycustomeventargs-instead-of-standard).

Comment: Why are you trying to call your button click event handler directly? That should get called when the user clicks the button. If you want, you can split the logic out into another function and have the event handler call that function...

Comment: It seems like you have a slight misunderstanding of what [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/awbftdfh.aspx) are and how they work.

Comment: Although the answers here try to explain why this approach won't work, I think the main problem here is the OP's lack of understanding regarding the whole event concept. In short, he is trying to make something work without investing the time needed to understand how it is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
EventHandler eh = (o, args) => settingButton_Click(o, args, username, password);
this.MyButton.Click += eh;
```

The first statement creates an EventHandler instance which has the right signature (i.e. it accept two parameters). The implementation of this event handler delegates to the settingButton_Click method adding two extra parameters.

If you want to override/ignore the 'object' and 'args' values, so that they have the values shown in your OP, you can do that like this:

```
EventHandler eh = (o, args) => settingButton_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty, username, password);
this.MyButton.Click += eh;
```

The main point is that the event handler must have the right signature. Another way to pass the parameters is via instance fields:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    string username;
    string password;
    public MainForm(string username, string password)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // set field values
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    void settingButton_Click(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        // get field values
        frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(this.username, this.password);
        _settings.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but do you think an event raised by a control should take the properties of two independent controls as its arguments?

Comment: It's clever... but the args parameter isn't being used as intended. Overriding the EventArgs class is the intent of the method signature.

Comment: Its clean but what's the point in creating an event handler with the lambda for code that is not actually an event?

Comment: `string username, string password` aren't properties of two independent controls: they seem to be constructor parameters. The alternative would be to save the constructor parameters as instance fields, from where they could be read in the event-handling method.

Comment: @ChrisW I have used the second example you provided, but the value of username in statement this.username = username; is null while username in the same statement has the value I want, how can it be?

Answer (score 1):

Click `event` *requires the certain rigid signature*, that is `(object sender, EventArgs e);`
so willy-nilly you have to put it like that (no other options avaliable):

```
  private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
  }
```

But there're no restrictions *inside* the method, so why don't you *get user and password there*?

```
  private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String user = ...
    String password = ...

    frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(user, pass);
    _settings.Show();   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do that because the method has to match a specific signature, similar to this one:

```
void click_handler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

An alternative would be to get user and pass somewhere else:

```
private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string user = ... ,
        pass = ... ;

    frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(user, pass);
    _settings.Show();   
}
```

Just out of curiosity, what did you expect to happen with your code?

**EDIT**

To reflect your question edit, simply create another function rather than messing with custom EventArgs and such (it's not worth for such a simple work imo):

```
private void showSettings(string user, string pass) {
    frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(user, pass);
    _settings.Show();
}

private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string user = ... ,
        pass = ... ;

    showSettings(user, pass);
}

public MainForm(string username, string password)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    showSettings(username, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will never work. Remove string pass and string user out of the button event constructor.

On that page make a global variable for string user and string pass. Set these variable values elsewhere within the same class. Then you can access the variables for user and pass within your button click event.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create a class that overrides the EventArgs object and pass that in. Ex:

```
public class Credentials : EventArgs {

    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public MainForm(string username, string password)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var cred = new Credentials(){User = username, Password = password};
    settingButton_Click(this, cred);
}

private void settingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cred = (Credentials)e;
    frmSetting _settings = new frmSetting(cred.User, cred.Password);
    _settings.Show();   
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how he'd pass his new `EventArgs` to his event handler.